# $G$ be a $p$-supersoluble group. and $O_{p'}(G ) = 1$ then $G$ is supersoluble

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-supersoluble group. If $O_{p'}(G ) = 1$ then $G$ is supersoluble.

Comment: Yes, that's right! Note that $C_G(O_p(G)) \le O_p(G)$, and $Q := G/C_G(O_p(G))$ acts faithfully on $O_p(G)$ and stabilizes a normal series of $O_p(G)$ with cyclic factor groups. But the automorphism group of a cyclic group is abelian, so $Q'$ centralizes each of these cyclic factor groups, and hence $Q'$ is a $p$-group, so $Q=G/O_p(G)$ is abelian.